# Testing Node.js API with Jest

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, testing, jestjs

I need to implement unit tests for my Node.js API. In the API I use nothing but vanilla Node.js. Testing framework is Jest. I have tests at the moment but they all require the server to be up before running the tests (I use supertest for that).

So the question is how I can test API endpoints without actually running the server?

Comment: you couldnt test when server is down , so you could use ENV variable to define test port and run test instance of server and do unit testing

Comment: @mohammadNaimi yeah thanks. I guess that's the only way

Answer (score 1):

> So the question is how I can test API endpoints without actually running the server?

I would use [nock](https://github.com/nock/nock). It is an HTTP server mocking library for Node.js.

> Nock can be used to test modules that perform HTTP requests in isolation.

See the [usage](https://github.com/nock/nock#usage) documentation.

```js
const nock = require('nock')

const scope = nock('https://api.github.com')
  .get('/repos/atom/atom/license')
  .reply(200, {
    license: {
      key: 'mit',
      name: 'MIT License',
      spdx_id: 'MIT',
      url: 'https://api.github.com/licenses/mit',
      node_id: 'MDc6TGljZW5zZTEz',
    },
  })
```

Basically you create a mocking scope for a given URL and then any test that makes an HTTP request to a mocked scope will be intercepted by `nock`.

You probably want to set up your mocked scopes in a `beforeAll` or `beforeEach` Jest block.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Will look into that nock